# Dygraph only highlighting 1 graph

Tags: dygraphs

So I made my graph with multiple series but for some reason I can only highlight the first graph that has been made.
The array is in following format:

```
Date, value1, value2

1, 10, null

2, null, 20
```

[Can't embed images yet so here's a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp99d.png)

```
for (arg in arguments){
        //data = arguments[arg][0];
        for(timestamp in arguments[arg][0]){
            data = [];
            if (arguments[arg][0][timestamp] != "NaN"){
                data.push(new Date(timestamp*1000));
            }
            pos = arg+1
            for(c in arguments){
                if(c == arg){
                    // put value into data
                    if (arguments[arg][0][timestamp] != "NaN") {
                        data.push(Number(arguments[arg][0][timestamp]));
                    }   
                }
                else{
                    data.push(null);
                }
            }
            if (arguments[arg][0][timestamp] != "NaN"){
                waarden.push(data);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, share at least your code and what you already tried. thx.

Comment: My bad, code added. This is where I check which series it is and where a 'null' needs to be placed